# What's the purpose of a diode across capacitor after voltage regulator?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, diodes

I'm learning about power supplies at university and I have created 2 or 3 PCBs of this stuff, but recently I saw this schematic:
[image]

I have no idea of what exactly these diodes do in this circuit.  Can someone explain it, please?

Comment: protects the capacitors against reverse applied voltages (from outside)

Comment: @analogsystemsrf thanks

Comment: @analogsystemsrf, you should post your answer as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those two diodes perform a useful function when the external load is connected between the power supply outputs (this configuration doubles the voltage potential of the positive rail).

In this case, if the load becomes short circuit then the two outputs will fight each other, one will become dominant and in this situation the diodes prevent one of the outputs (Capacitors) becoming reverse biased.

In addition, at power supply switch on, one of the rails will "come up" faster than the other one and in this situation the diodes prevent the "slow to rise rail" becoming reverse biased. I think the same situation can occur at power down.

To summarise, the diodes are reverse bias protection.

These two diodes should be rated for the full output current of the power supply.